# How to convert a Json String/Data to a Java Class?

Tags: java, android, json, postman

I'm new in Android and programming as well. I would like to build an Android app with user login and User Location tracer. What's the easiest way to convert a Json String to Java Class?

My Json String:

[image: Json String]

Comment: do you want to parse your json file , you want to show these data from json to your app !

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use ObjectMapper

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class YourClassDao {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  public YourClass load(String json) throws IOException {
    return objectMapper.readValue(
        json, YourClass.class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of approaches I have used are :

1. Using Jackson :

> ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
> Map<String,Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, UserDefinedClass.class);

2. Using gson: gson is an open sourced java library used to serialize and deserialize Java objects to JSON. Import the library in maven

> ```
>    <dependency> 
>       <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId> 
>       <artifactId>gson</artifactId> 
>       <version>2.6.2</version>     
>    </dependency>
> ```

> ```
> private static Organisation getOrganisationObject() { 
>     String organisation = "{\"organisation_name\": \"TataMotors\",
>         \"Employee\" : \"2000\"}"; 
>
>     Gson gson = new Gson(); 
>     Organisation orgObject = gson.fromJson(OrganisationJson, 
>                         Organisation.class); 
>
>     return orgObject; 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Three ways you can achieve this :**

1. String to JSON Object using Gson

The Gson is an open-source library to deal with JSON in Java programs. You can convert JSON String to Java object in just 2 lines by using Gson as shown below :

Gson g = new Gson(); 
YourClass c = g.fromJson(jsonString, YourClass.class)

You can also convert a Java object to JSON by using toJson() method as shown below

String str = g.toJson(c);

---

2. JSON String to Java object using JSON-Simple
   The JSON-Simple is another open-source library which supports JSON parsing and formatting. The good thing about this library is its small size, which is perfect for memory constraint environments like J2ME and **Android**.

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);

---

3. String to JSON - Jackson Example
   Jackson is I guess the most popular JSON parsing library in Java world. Following one-liner convert JSON string representing a soccer player into a Java class representing player:

YourClass obj = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, YourClass.class);